# Eclipse - Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient)

Tags: android, eclipse, git, apache, dependencies

I am trying to install `Eclipse Git Team Provider` and `JGit` in my version of `Eclipse ADT` via `Help > Install New Software > "EGit - http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates"` but the installation fails with this error...

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Java implementation of Git -
>   optional Http support using Apache httpclient 3.3.1.201403241930-r
>   (org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache.feature.group 3.3.1.201403241930-r)
>   Missing requirement: Apache HttpComponents HttpClient OSGi bundle
>   4.1.3.v201209201135 (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient 4.1.3.v201209201135) requires 'package org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.4.0' but it could not be found   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient 3.3.1.201403241930-r
>   (org.eclipse.jgit.http.apache.feature.group 3.3.1.201403241930-r)
>       To: org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient [4.1.3.v201209201135]

It's saying I need to install either `org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient 4.1.3.v201209201135` or `package org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.4.0` (although, I'm not clear which one is missing, or whether both are missing?)...

How do I add it/them to `Eclipse`?

I can find lots of info on how to add jars to the library of an individual project, but that's not what I need as I think (correct me if I'm wrong) that I need to add them to Eclipse via `Help > Install New Software`.

And I have seen lots of people post similar problems with other dependencies, but have not found an answer that explains how to add this particular software.

I'm new to Eclipse, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which is `Eclipse` distribution your are trying for?

Comment: When I go into Help > About ADT, it just says: Android Developer Tools. Build: buildId. Do you need any more info / where to find?

Comment: I'm using `Eclipse Indigo` and I've used url mentioned above but I successfully installed the `EGit`, that is why I'm asking which Eclipse you are using??

Comment: I'm using Eclipse ADT. If you need any more info than I've already provided, please can you tell me where / how to find it.

Comment: It's Release 4.2.0 according to my file:///P:/Program%20Files/Eclipse/eclipse/readme/readme_eclipse.html . I don't really want to redo the whole installation process though as that takes hours. If there's a solution that means I can stick with the current version, that would be great.

Comment: It's Eclipse Juno - just noticed it on the startup splash screen.

Comment: @SuperUser: I just had a look at [review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1367918/super-user?tab=activity&sort=revisions). Please don't add backtick-quoting for things that aren't code. It is *not* meant to be used for highlighting/emphasizing parts of text; they're only meant to format inline code statements.

Comment: @AmalMurali OK, I know that `backtick-quoting not meant to be used for highlighting/emphasizing parts of text`, but there are **tons** of **Qs & Ans** which have used to `highlighting/emphasizing parts of text` using `backtick-quoting`, after all **Thanks** for your _review_

Comment: @SuperUser: That doesn't mean you should be doing the same thing. Please have a look at [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209305/user-making-inappropriate-edits-with-backticks).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem, at least on my installation of Eclipse.

What I did was get the name of the missing package and googled it.

1. Download the package from here:
   http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi
   Selecting the package under the "Binaries" section
2. Unzip the file and extract "commons-codec-1.9.jar"
3. Copy this Jar file to your Eclipse installation directory "Eclipse\plugins"
4. Rename it with the name of your missing package.
   (In my case "org.apache.commons.codec.binary_1.4.0.jar")
5. Now repeat the steps to install EGit and it should work.

Obviously there are many things that could be different with your installation, I am using Eclipse version 4.2.0

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me.
Note: In step 4, replace the space between package name and number with '_', for me the missing package name was org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.6.0 and the corresponding file was org.apache.commons.codec.binary_1.6.0.jar

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.2 and I faced the same problem as user1617737.

It's a little obscure but I dare say the missing dependency is 'package org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.4.0'. I guess there is a problem with this JAR file in the EGit package itself.

Anyway, I was unable to find a solution, other than unmarking the following component to be installed:

Java implementation of Git - optional Http support using Apache httpclient  3.3.2.201404171909-r

In this way, EGit has been installed, though I don't know what features I may be missing.

Comment: Of course, the point is I cannot connect to the central server with PUSH, so I need to use GIT in command line.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I deleted an older version of org.apache.commons.codec.binary from the clipse/plugins directory. And placed the required "org.apache.commons.codec.binary 1.4.0.jar". Then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up in the end and used Eclipse Kepler, which worked fine.

Would be nice to know the solution though to the original problem if anyone knows it. I'm sure others will also get this problem.

Comment: The problem is still here, with Kepler one as well :/ :\

Comment: Thankfully, I don't have to use Eclipse any more. Are you able to switch to another IDE, like Netbeans?

Comment: yes, also  left Eclipse with all its issues. Succesfully using NetBeans since that.

Comment: Eclipse should really come with a warning!! :-D

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with `Eclipse Indigo Version: 3.7.2`. I tried to install older versions of EGit but still I had other problems. Finally EGit `version 1.3` was installed with success.