# Error while trying to export eclipse product using wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, product

I am getting an error using the eclipse product export wizard. I attached a screen shot the error. The application itself runs out of eclipse with no problems. I know I have the dependency in the proper location. If it helps my company uses Eclipse Indigo. Additionally, a side thing I have noticed is if I add the osgi plugin to the start levels on the configuration tab the product builds. However after I build and install the program it won't run because of an illegal argument exception.

Any info would be appreciated.[image].
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to give you 2 suggestions:

1. Check your PATH environment variable and make sure it's pointing to
   the right JDK. that was the issue. Hope this will help.
2. Secondly you can download the related jar file and keep it in related folder. There is a good example is given here: [Eclipse - Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found (org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23062903/eclipse-cannot-complete-the-install-because-one-or-more-required-items-could-n)